# Android WebChromeClient WebView onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt never fired

Tags: android, webview, gps, webchromeclient

I have a webpage with a WatchPosition call which works fine in regular browsers. However, the dialog for  requesting GPS Permission never shows when the webpage is loaded from a WebView with WebChromeClient and onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt is never called.

```
public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
     public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
         Log.d("geolocation permission", "permission >>>"+origin);
         callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
}

 public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView Browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Browser);

    WebSettings webSettings = Browser.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    Browser.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    Browser.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

    Browser.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.102/");


}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` only shown when the app is first run.use `adb uninstall your_pack_name` to remove then install it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

onGeolocationShowPrompt doesn't actually show a prompt itself, it is just a method that gets called when the page requests your Geolocation. You'll need to create your own prompt for the user like shown below (placed inside the onGeolocatioonShowPrompt method):

```
final boolean remember = true;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Locations");
builder.setMessage(origin + " Would like to use your Current Location").setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // origin, allow, remember
                                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Don't Allow",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // origin, allow, remember
                                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                                }
                            });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Is this new? I used that implementation and was working fine before (like ayear back?) and now it just shows it's blocked, no prompt shown whatsoever (as of July 2019).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for how to fix the "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt is never used" message like I was, this should help. If this is your issue it doesn't matter what's put in the method if it's never called.

In your onCreate:

```java
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new customWebView());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new customChromeClient());
```

Custom classes:

```java
private class customChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);

        //check for permissions or show your dialog etc
    }
}

//other methods you may want to override
private class customWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone in future.

Example and where I found the answer:
https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/ad84740c9bffa7e255c8

Answer (score 0):

Well in case when location is turned off and if website request location then `webview` call `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` but only one time. To make that work, means call `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` every time when website request location I did this:

```
inner class MyChromeClient: WebChromeClient()
    {

        override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin: String?, callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback?) {
            // Geolocation permissions coming from this app's Manifest will only be valid for devices with API_VERSION < 23.
            // On API 23 and above, we must check for permission, and possibly ask for it.
            //callback?.invoke(origin,true,false)

            val permission=Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.M || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,permission)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // we're on SDK < 23 OR user has already granted permission
                callback?.invoke(origin,true,false)
            }
            else{

                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@WebViewActivity,permission))
                {
                    // user clicked on don't asked again
                    alert("Allow location permission to access this feature"){
                        yesButton {
                            val intent=Intent()
                            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                            intent.data= Uri.fromParts("package",packageName,null)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            callback?.invoke(origin,false,false)
                        }
                        noButton {
                            callback?.invoke(origin,false,false)
                        }
                    }.show()
                }
                else{
                    // permission not granted yet
                    this@WebViewActivity.callback=callback
                    this@WebViewActivity.origin=origin
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@WebViewActivity, arrayOf(permission),100)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Add onRequestPermissionsResult Code:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && requestCode==100)
        {
            if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if (callback!=null)
                    callback?.invoke(origin,true,false)
                return
            }
            else{
                callback?.invoke(origin,false,false)
            }
        }
        callback?.invoke(origin,false,false)
    }
```

The point is, if you want that `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` should call again you need to call `callback?.invoke(origin,false,false)`, with these exact value in parameter inside `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt`